# When is throwing/catching general exception acceptable

Tags: java, exception

One of the projects I inherited is riddled with tons of try/catch blocks catching the general `Exception`. I've been slowly but surely refactoring this, but there are so many, such that I have been contemplating bringing this up as a concern in a meeting. This got me to thinking...Is there ever really a case where catching the general exception is justified in a production environment? I could not think of a case where I NEEDED to catch the general exception, but I'm also a fairly recent grad and I'm sure there's tons that I don't know. I did a little research, and I can find lot's of reasons why NOT to catch the general exception, but nothing concrete on when this practice is justified. Obviously if you're calling a method that already throws Exception you have to catch it. But is there ever a reason some method could throw `Exception` and it should not be refactored to throw the specific exception.?

Comment: Quickest reason? If you throw it, and don't catch it, the app server **stops**. That's a pretty compelling reason to be careful with refactoring.

Comment: How is this a possible duplicate?? I know WHEN to throw an exception. The question is about when is throwing general exception acceptable..

Comment: At the end of the output pipeline it makes sense. For example if you have several swing Actions with an actionPerformed: make one base class with try-catch that calls an abstract protected onActionPerformed. Otherwise exceptions at several points with logging is a terrible good way to make the code unreadable and prevent refactoring.

Comment: All exceptions shouldn't be handled the same way, and it makes your code less readable, thus it doesn't make sense to stick to the superclass.

Comment: @Dukeling a good point, NumberFormatException to name one. But catching+logging is simply just sticking a toe in the water.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch point taken. I guess my question should maybe be when is throwing the general exception acceptable. Obviously if you're calling a method that throws `Exception` you have to catch it. But is there ever a reason some method could throw `Exception` and it should not be refactored to throw the specific exception.?

Comment: @ElroyJetson Now we're in the realm of opinion. "Ever" is broad too, but we could speculate - if there's some absurd number of specific exceptions a method might throw, then you have two choices: one) wrap all of the possible exceptions in a custom exception or two) throw a generic exception (or even worse, [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)).

Comment: ...and that usually means the method has design issues because it needs to throw so many different checked exceptions, so refactoring is applicable there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catching general `Exception` isn't best practice, because if you are catching exception you are telling that you can handle it and recover from that exception state, but if you can't recover then it might be better to fail than to keep working with very unpredictable state.

Another thing that can happen is to catch exception that is supposed to be handled at higher level which can again lead to dangerous state.

There is possibility that code was written before Java 7 when multi-catch was introduced so they used `Exception` instead of writing each separately, or that developer wasn't familiar with this.

Only case in which catching `Exception` is justified, in my opinion at least, is at top of the application(`main`) - catch all exceptions that are not handled at lower levels, log them and exit for safety reasons, and crash nicely and show reasonable message to end user.

This brings us to another thing, and that is throwing `Exception`, same as with catching one you shouldn't throw `Exception`, that is same like returning Object from every method, you lose identity.

If this two things are very common in project you are working on maybe you should consider mentioning that to senior developer.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. A reason it could be justifiable. I'm just trying to see things from someone else's perspective before I write his/her code off as being 'bad' code. I always assume there is a reason for weird things I sometimes find in other people's code. Many of times have I assumed something to be 'bad' or senseless, only to be provided a good reason as to why it was coded a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

Throw `Exception` *only* if you *need to* throw `Exception`, specifically. If you throw too-general an exception, you are effectively just shouting "there is a problem", without giving specific information as to what that problem is.

Catch `Exception` *only* if `Exception` is thrown, specifically. If you catch too general an exception, you're losing the opportunity to handle specific exceptions in the correct way.

Throwing `Exception` is the equivalent of returning `Object` instead of a more-specific type which would be useful to the caller; catching `Exception` is the equivalent of assigning a return value to an `Object` variable, rather than a more specific type that you could do useful things with. Basically: you are discarding available type information.

Sometimes you *have to* throw `Exception`, because you are writing a general framework. For example, `Callable.call` throws `Exception`, because you don't know what code will be executed there, so allowing it to throw `Exception` means that you don't constrain users of the class. And consequently, if you're calling a `Callable`, you need to catch `Exception`; but you need to do it with care.

The vast majority of people aren't (or shouldn't be) writing frameworks, and so you shouldn't be throwing or catching `Exception`.

There is good advice on this in *Effective Java*, Item 61, " Throw exceptions appropriate to the abstraction" (this is the number in 2nd Ed; don't know about 3rd Ed). Basically: you almost certainly don't want to throw `Exception`, but you might want to throw `IOException` rather than `FileNotFoundException`, if the fact that you're reading from a *file* isn't relevant to your API.

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear. I understand when to throw exceptions, and also how to refactor this. Basically, what I'm looking for is to know whether or not the person who wrote these try/catches could possible have some reason to have not caught the specific exception, and instead caught the general exception. Basically, I don't want to refactor this man's code if there is some reason why catching the specific exception would somehow be a problem.

Comment: @ElroyJetson I say "only throw when" and "only catch when". If these conditions don't apply, you shouldn't be throwing or catching `Exception` respectively.

Comment: so to your first point: "Throw Exception only if you need to" Got it. But when would someone NEED to throw exception? What is an example of when throwing `Exception` needed to be done.

Comment: For example, if you stumble across some code where whoever wrote it throws `Exception`. Simply put, is there EVER a reason to NOT refactor this to throw the specific exception?

Comment: There is good advice on this in *Effective Java*, the item called something like "Throw exceptions appropriate to the abstraction". Basically: you almost certainly don't want to throw `Exception`, but you should maybe throw `IOException` rather than `FileNotFoundException`.